# How to parse a certain type of configuration file

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Recently I encounter an interview question. I was required to write code for expression evaluation. The expression format looks like this:

```
   B=10;
   A={
      A=100;
      B=BDE;
      C=C;
      D={
         A=windows;
         B=mac;
      C={
         A=redhat;
         B=ubuntu;
        };
   };
   A+={
       A=200;
       E=1000;
      };
```

To represent the key of the expression, period delimitated method is used. For example, A.B represents the element B in Map A, and  the value of A.B is BDE; similarly,  the value of A.D.C.A is redhat. the the represent string is called 'path expression'.

the configuration also support append and override operation. for the above example, we use += operation to append or override the value in Map A. now the value of A.A is 200, and the value of A.E is 1000;

Now, given a configuration strings and the key path of configuration, I was required to return the value of configuration based the configuration strings.

**Rules**

1)  the key name and his value only contains alphabet(A-Z,a-z) and number(0-9), no other characters;

2) if cannot find the value or the expression point to a map, please output "N/A"

3) if find the value, please output the value. no spaces when output the value.

Input and Output

there are three part sin the input. the first line contains two integers indicates  the number of congiruation lines(M) and the number of expressions(N).

M<=100, N<=100. the following M lines are the confugration and the last N lines are expression. every configuration line contains one or more configurations. every line length less than 1000.

**Input :**

2 2

A={A=1;B=2;C=3;E={A=100;};};

A+={D=4;E={B=10;C=D;};};

A.E.B

B.D.E

Output

A.E.B=10

B.D.E=N/A

**My thoughts**

I was thinking about using a N-nary tree to represent the expression. For example, the expression: A = {A = 1;D = 1;B = {C = 1,D = {D = 1,F = 2};};}; can be represented as:

```
                            (A,-)
                         /    |    \
                      (A,1) (D,1)  (B,-)
                                  /    \
                                (C,1)   (D,-)
                                       /    \
                                     (D,1)  (F,2)
```

Since a N-nary tree can be represented as a binary tree. Thus, all append or search operations would be either the insert or search operations for a binary tree. It seems that this approach works. But I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about putting all children in a hash map (since that's what interviewers like)

```
Node{
    String val;
    HashMap<String, Node> children;
    Node(int val){
        this.val = val;
        children = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this method doesn't work because even if you put all children in a hash map, it is still complicated for you to find the corresponding value for a key. E.g A={A={A=B};};     In this case, what if we want to find A[A][A]'s value?

Comment: suppose the first node is declared as node, you will do node.children.get('A').children.get('A').val